# JS Synchronous Calls - Email with Attachment

Tags: javascript, email, email-template, custom-button

I'm trying to set up a JS button on a SFDC object record that sends an email to a recipient with a specific attachment from the Notes and Attachment related object. Would I theoretically be able to query an attachment from a specific file name and attach it to the email using a sforce.connection.sendEmail() method? See below for an example of the sendEmail method I got from [this link](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp).

```
sendEmail Example:
// single mail request

var singleRequest = new sforce.SingleEmailMessage();
singleRequest.replyTo = "jsmith@acme.com";
singleRequest.subject = "sent through ajax test driver";

singleRequest.plainTextBody = "this test went through ajax";
singleRequest.toAddresses = ["noone@nowhere.com"];

// mass mail request - need to get email template ID

var queryResponse = sforce.connection.query("select id from emailtemplate");
var templatedId = queryResponse.getArray("records")[0].Id;
var massRequest = new sforce.MassEmailMessage();
massRequest.targetObjectIds = [globalContact.id];
massRequest.replyTo = "jsmith@acme.com";
massRequest.subject = "sent through ajax test driver";
massRequest.templateId = templateId;

var sendMailRes = sforce.connection.sendEmail([singleRequest, massRequest]);
```

Comment: Pretty simple with `Apex` if you are willing to create a `Visualforce` button instead. You can have it redirect right back to the detail page.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically it *might* is possible. Although salesforce in its ajax toolkit file(connection.js) do not provide any reference to the fileAttachments, I  still gave it a try.  If you see the `connection.js` file you will find that the with every object that salesforce creates and sets the '_xsiType' property. Now this xsiType property is the same as the complexType in the enterprise WSDL.

So decided to create a new `emailFileAttachment` object  and  associated it with the singleEmailmessage. But unfortunately it errored out with the message:

> No body specified in the file attachment

I tried with multiple body type : base64EncodedString and blob but still no luck. This may be remotely related to an issue mentioned [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64299/save-attachment-with-remote-objects).

```
//I defined this function
sforce.EmailFileAttachment= function() {
};

//set the xsiType to emailFileAttachment
sforce.EmailFileAttachment.prototype = new sforce.Xml("EmailFileAttachment");
sforce.EmailFileAttachment.prototype._xsiType = "EmailFileAttachment";

//Created the object. 
var fileAttachment = new sforce.EmailFileAttachment();
fileAttachment.body = new Blob(['iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='], {type: 'application/octet-binary'});
fileAttachment.name = 'howdy.png';


var singleRequest = new sforce.SingleEmailMessage();
singleRequest.replyTo = "jsmith@acme.com";
singleRequest.subject = "sent through ajax test driver";

singleRequest.plainTextBody = "this test went through ajax";
singleRequest.toAddresses = ["test@acme.com"];
singleRequest.fileAttachments = [fileAttachment]; //set the file in singleRequestObject.

var sendMailRes = sforce.connection.sendEmail([singleRequest]);
console.log('Single Email meesgae response ' + sendMailRes );
```