# Save attachment with Remote Objects

Tags: javascript, attachment, blob, remote-objects, base64

is it even possible to save attachment with remote objects to salesforce?

I tried this:

1. construct remote object model

`<apex:remoteObjects jsNamespace="MyModel">
    <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Attachment" fields="Name,Id,ParentId,Body" >
    </apex:remoteObjectModel>
</apex:remoteObjects>`

2. create attachment

`var blob='test body';
var ctDetails = {Name:'test',parentid:'some_id',Body:blob};
var ct = new MyModel.Attachment();
ct.create(ctDetails);`

I get response:

`Body: value not of required type...`

I thought problem has to be with body encoding and I tried to convert to base64 (btoa('test body')), use Blob class in javascript. Nothing works, response is the same everytime.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Could you include the controller class as well so that we can see what the remote action is defined to accept?

Comment: There is no controller class, because it is just visual force page. Remote objects are intended just for Vf. See: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_remote_objects.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fpages_remote_objects.htm|SkinName=webhelp

Comment: The body needs to be a BLOB not a text string

Comment: @Eric: I tried the response from `readAsDataURL()` method, converted to Blob as mentioned here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript) and then tried, but no luck.. I tried using the `.readAsArrayBuffer()` but even this failed. would you mind sharing the code that's working for you?

Comment: Can you retrieve a known `Attachment` via remote objects and then examine the encoding of the body? This may indicate how you should encode the body, assuming symmetric treatment for retrieval and creation.

Comment: I've tried that and get the following error when trying to retrieve body field of attachment: `Visualforce Remoting Exception: No serializer found for class common.udd.object.EncryptableFfxBlobField$DeferredEncryptableFfxBlobValueImpl`

If I try to retrieve attachment without body field, it works normally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the error message you get when you attempt to retrieve the body of an attachment:

> Visualforce Remoting Exception: No serializer found for class common.udd.object.EncryptableFfxBlobField$DeferredEncryptableFfxBlobValueImpl

It would appear that you can't work with blob fields in Visualforce Remote Objects.

I'll see if I can find an official reference for the supported field types...

- [Visual Force Remoting](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000009966IAA)

> VF Remoting [does not] support Blob data type.  See VF Remoting docs for supported types.

Comment: This makes sense, which is why we're unable to retrieve or create. But had the error message said `Attachment Object not supported for remoteObject` then that would have been the end of it. But the Error message says 'Body : not of required type' which only makes the developer think that there could be a data type that can be used.  Salesforce should update their documentation on the supported objects for `Remote Objects`

Comment: I agree, it is confusing. I've tried [pinging @SalesforceDocs](https://twitter.com/FishOfPrey/status/572849931943325699) to see if they can elaborate.

Comment: Got a confirmation from Salesforce that this is a bug in the system and will be worked upon in the coming release.

Comment: They have created a knowledge article on the same https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Blob-datatype-is-not-supported-for-Remote-Objects&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

If you are using javascript remoting to upload document to salesforce, you will be limited by the 6MB heap limit of apex. But actually salesforce supports uploading attachments of size upto 25MB. I had come across such scenario previously to upload document to salesforce record from javascript. I used AJAX API to solve the problem.

Try using HTML5 file reader API in combination with AJAX API call to upload attachment. HTML5 file reader will help in showing preview of files(images) and checking whether file size is exceeding 25MB and AJAX API will help in uploading upto 25MB through nothing more than 200 lines of javascript.

Comment: I have already implemented it using REST API and its working beautifully. But I wanted to be able to create it using RemoteObjects which I am unable to.